# How to implement a ThreadPoolExecutor with rampUp time

Tags: java, threadpool

I would like to know if anyone has implemented a threadpool in which a rampup time can be specified. for example , if we create a threadpool of size 50 and specify a rampup time of 50 seconds. 1 thread should be created every second. I tried to extends ThreadPoolExecutor in Java by overriding the beforeExecute method but later realized that it would call beforeExecute method before executing any Runnable.

Comment: Why would you do this? If you know what size you want, why not just make it that size?  Note: it will only create threads as they are required which can be more efficient than your solution.

Comment: Put another way, increasing the thread pool size without having waiting tasks just changes a setting, but doesn't start a thread.

Comment: I want to load test application ..similar to what JMeter or LoadRunner does. So instead of starting the threads at once i want to ramp up the load over a period of time .

Comment: Would the Scheduled executor work?  You could start the first Runnable in 1 second, the second in 2 seconds, .. , and the last Runnable in 50 seconds.